# SAML 2.0 integration with a service provider

Tags: saml, saml-2.0

we currently run our IdP on Firebase auth. One of our partner (service provider) only supports SAML 2.0. They want us to send in a request with a payload to a URL with User's email address.

I do not have much experience SAML 2.0, what you guys think the best approach for this would be?

Sorry for a vague question.

Thanks,
Sam

Comment: SAML 2.0 is the current standard (there were some additional extensions / profiles added later on). As far as I understood Firebase auth it's only performing the authenitcation an IdP would need. Which IdP are you using?
Normally you just need to exchange saml meta data and the partner app just performs SAML SP-initiated SSO flow. 
Please keep in mind that SAML was primarily invented to perform cookie-less, standards based SSO for the Web.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, You will have to configure your SP and IDP by exchanging the metadata(via a URL or XML file or manually). From the question, it seems that you are looking for IDP initiated SSO. After a user successfully authenticates with the IDP, the IDP sends a response(XML payload) which contains the user identifier typically a username or email. The SP will read the payload and after verifying the data it will create the user session in your SP.
The SAML response looks something like [this](https://www.samltool.com/generic_sso_res.php).